# Angular project from stackblitz - no Bootstrap styles

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular8, stackblitz

I have downloaded the following project from StackBlitz:

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-wtpacb)

I had to modify app.module by adding this code:

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
```

and this:

```
providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: ''}],
```

After that it ran, but Bootstrap 4 is not taken into account. What might be wrong?

Thanks